# php trim() not working to remove empty blank spaces

Tags: php

I have a situation where i have to ignore empty data when processing the set of string. Some of the string are valid and some comes with just white spaces (created using spacebar in keyboard)

for example the data would come like this in the program...

```
 $x = "  ";
```

In this case i have to tell this $x is empty though there are two white spaces in it.

I tried using PHP empty() function but it returns false. i tried PHP trim() function but it does not help to remove this empty white spaces for the variable to become empty.

How can i get this validated as empty in PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` removes all the whitespaces from the beginning and end of a string and returns the trimmed string

So you'll need to feed the returned string of `trim()` to `empty()`:

```php
<?php

$x = "  "; 

var_dump(empty($x));         // false
var_dump(trim($x));          // string(0) ""
var_dump(empty(trim($x)));   // true
```

---

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6VCwVZBSUFByVqBi6sssSg@pTS3QCM1t6CkUkOlQlPTGiFYUpSZiy4GUQiX0bT@/x8A)

Comment: trim works only when there is some string content with whitespace. my scenario is only whitespace on which trim is not working.

Comment: Don't think thats true, please click the 'try it online' to see the above code in action.

Comment: @Joseph `empty(trim($x))` returns true when I try it with your question's value. If it doesn't for you, you might need to look for weird special characters within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a custom function for check possible multiple white-spaces.

```
$str = "      ";

function isOnlyWhitespace($str) {
   return strlen($str) === substr_count($str, ' ') ? true : false;
}

echo isOnlyWhitespace($str); // 1
```